# Handling Touch Events on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, gesture-recognition, iphone-privateapi

I am exploring the way touch events are handled on iOS devices. I referred the book: [iOS Open Application Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596518561.do). Working on that, I am overriding the mouseDown, mouseUp methods and simply displaying the co-ordinates in an alert box. However, the overridden methods never get called. The following is the code for the newView Class that derives from UIView:

```
-(void) _mouseDown: (GSEventRef) event{
CGPoint point =GSEventGetLocationInWindow(event);
UIAlertView* alert;
NSString* alertString =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f %f", point.x, point.y];
alert = [[UIALertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:alertString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
}

-(BOOL) canHandleGestures{
return YES;
}
```

Is there any part that I missing ? Also, is there an alternative way of getting information on touch events and handling them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better starting point would be here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html

These are the methods you may override in a UIView subclass:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
```

for getting touch events from UIView subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You Have to use `gesturerecognizer` (like [uitapgesturerecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [uiswipegesturerecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [UITouch events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html))